# Write recursive function that prints 1 and n zeroes in C

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have trouble writing a **recursive** function in C:

```
void func(int n)
```

which for a given number n prints "1" and *n* zeroes after it.

for example:

```
func(3);
```

prints: 1000

```
func(5);
```

prints: 100000

**No global variables (outside the function) are allowed and argument count must not be increased. No other helper functions allowed.**

Comment: Is this homework? And what have you tried?

Comment: Is this [***homework***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Comment: @EricFinn I don't know how to detect that it is the first time the function has been called to print the "1". The zeroes are not a problem to be print.

Comment: If you know the answer, please do post it

Comment: @GladToHelp You answered neither of my questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int k){
  if(k==0){
    printf("1");
    return;
  }
  func(k-1);
  printf("0");
}

int main(){
  func(3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Giving out homework answers like this denies the asker the opportunity to learn.

Comment: this doesn't even work.. it prints the 1 last

Comment: @JohnCorbett Trace through, line by line.

Comment: right, I wasn't thinking :P silly me, recursion prevents the 0s from being printed until the end

Comment: this code misses the trick which was intended by the professor for his students.

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers:

1. Why do you think you must print "1" only on the first call of the function?
2. Why can't you print it on the last call of the recursive function and then print all the 0's?
3. How will you determine if a call to the function is the last call in the recursive way? (Can the value of "n" hold the answer?)

Comment: 1. Alright I saw the answer, I guess I had a bad idea 2. same as 1. 3. Well in some cases "n" (the argument) can hold the answer. For example, if I needed 000001 instead of 100000 I could detect if it is the last call by checking if n == 0

Comment: @GladToHelp, In this case also if (n == 0) can help, if you utilize recursion effectively to print 1 first and then 0s. : )

Comment: agreed. I already saw the solution (correct answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into static variables. you could set a static variable to tell if your function is being called recursively or not. If you're not allowed to use global variables, it's just a tricky work-around. And when your recursion is done, just set it back for the next call.

Comment: Sorry, but that is terrible advice.

Comment: It will work, but it would be quite unusual approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using two functions, for example `func` and `func_rec`. `func` will print the `1` and it will once call the recursive function `func_rec` which will print only zeros (recursively).

Comment: The point was to use only one function with only one argument

Comment: @GladToHelp That limitation wasn't specified in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n)
{
    static one = 1;
    if (one == 1){
        printf("1");
        one--;
        func(n - 1);
    }
    else {
        if (n < 0){
            printf("\n");
            return;
        }
        else {
            printf("0");
            func(n - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    func(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is very trivial so, even it seems that its a homework, i'm giving out the code.

Your earlier question suggests that you are not so much into c coding. What i'm trying to do is to reduce your frustration by giving out the code, but with a twist.

Please answer us why the code i've given is not a "pure" function? why this solution should be discarded with ones which have global storage.

You should learn this stuff, its pretty interesting :)